# Determining the average probability of error

Tags: signal-detection, random, probability

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> In a binary PAM system, the input to the detector is
> $$y_m = a_m+n_m+i_m$$
> where $a_m = \pm1$ is the desired signal, $n_m$ is a zero-mean Gaussian random variable
> with variance $\sigma_n^2$ and $i_m$ represents the ISI due to channel distortion. The ISI term
> is a random variable which takes the values, $\frac{-1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2}$ with probabilities $\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}$ respectively. Determine the average probability of error as a function of $\sigma_n^2$.

**My try:** I think the probability of error is $$P_e = \mathbb{P}(y_m<0 |a_m = 1) + \mathbb{P}(y_m\gt 0|a_m = -1)$$According to the definition of conditional probability, we have $$\mathbb{P}(y_m<0 |a_m = 1) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(y_m<0 \cap a_m = 1)}{\mathbb{P}(a_m = 1)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(n_m+i_m<-1)}{\mathbb{P}(a_m = 1)}$$ By law of total probability $$\mathbb{P}(n_m+i_m<-1) = \mathbb{P}(n_m+i_m<-1\cap i_m = \frac{-1}{2}) + \mathbb{P}(n_m+i_m<-1\cap i_m = 0) + \mathbb{P}(n_m+i_m<-1\cap i_m = \frac{1}{2}) = \mathbb{P}(n_m<\frac{-1}{2}) + \mathbb{P}(n_m<-1) + \mathbb{P}(n_m<\frac{-3}{2})$$
Each term can be written as a function of $\sigma_n^2$ easily. So it seems we need $\mathbb{P}(a_m = \pm1)$ instead of $\mathbb{P}(i_m = \pm\frac{1}{2},0)$ which can't be true because we should certainly use values of $\mathbb{P}(i_m = \pm\frac{1}{2},0)$. What's my mistake here? Also is there any difference between "average probability of error" and "probability of error"?

Comment: Be careful not to count events twice. For example, if the noise is less than -1.5, there's an error regardless of the value of $i_m$. Also, in your first equation, the two terms on the right-hand side are equal?

Comment: @MBaz Thanks for your reply, I fixed it. I think the term $\mathbb{P}(y_m<0 |a_m = 1) + \mathbb{P}(y_m\gt 0|a_m = -1)$ counts every events of interest exactly once. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. Now make sure you don't count noise events more than once.

Comment: @MBaz My main problem is computing $\mathbb{P}(y_m<0 |a_m = 1)$. I don't know if $$\mathbb{P}(y_m<0 |a_m = 1) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(y_m<0 \cap a_m = 1)}{\mathbb{P}(a_m = 1)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(n_m+i_m<-1)}{\mathbb{P}(a_m = 1)}$$ is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$
\mathbb{P}(n_m+i_m<-1\cap i_m = \frac{-1}{2})
$$
is equal to
$$
\mathbb{P}(n_m < -0.5)\mathbb{P}(i_m = -0.5) = 0.25\mathbb{P}(n_m < -0.5)
$$
since $n_m$ and $i_m$ are independent.

Another way to obtain the solution is to add the the probability of these three disjoint events:

- $n_m < -1.5$,
- $i_m = 0$ and $-1.5 < n_m < -1$,
- $i_m = -0.5$ and $-1 < n_m < -0.5$

In this case, we can add the three probabilities because the events are disjoint. To keep them disjoint, it is important to keep the noise ranges disjoint too; otherwise, you would be adding them multiple times.

Comment: Thanks. By the symmetry of the problem we have $\mathbb{P}(y_m<0 |a_m = 1) = \mathbb{P}(y_m\gt 0|a_m = -1)$, so I found the answer to be $P_e = 2\mathbb{P}(y_m<0 |a_m = 1) = 2(\frac{1}{4}Q(\frac{1}{2\sigma}) + \frac{1}{2}Q(\frac{1}{\sigma}) + \frac{1}{4}Q(\frac{3}{2\sigma}))$. Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite; you need to average the probabilities for $a_m=1$ and $a_m=-1$, not add them.

Comment: Would you explain more, please? An error will occur when $\{y_m<0 |a_m = 1\}$ or $\{y_m\gt 0|a_m = -1\}$ happen. So we need to add them to get the probability of error but you are saying that the answer is $\frac{1}{2}(\mathbb{P}(y_m<0 |a_m = 1)+ \mathbb{P}(y_m\gt 0|a_m = -1))$

Comment: Let $e$ stand for "error", $s_1$ for $a_m=1$ and $s_2$ for $a_m=-1$. You have calculated $P(e|s_1)$ and $P(e|s_2)$, but you want $P(e) = P(e \cap s_1)+P(e \cap s_2)$, which equals $P(e|s_1)P(s_1)+P(e|s_2)P(s_2)$.

Comment: I see. I was confusing conditional probability with joint probability. So the correct answer is $P_e = \frac{1}{4}Q(\frac{1}{2\sigma}) + \frac{1}{2}Q(\frac{1}{\sigma}) + \frac{1}{4}Q(\frac{3}{2\sigma})$. Thank you so much for your patience.